# My Vignere Cipher produces a segmentation fault, am I reading or writing an illegal memory location, or am I using pointers incorrectly?

Tags: c, encryption

My intent with this code is to make a vignere cipher.

I can compile my code with gcc but when I run the program and pass 2 strings in the command line I have a segmentation fault. Initially I had tried to control the int value of j with a separate if-statement in my for-loop such as:

---

```
if( i % strlen(msg) == 0) {
    j = 0;
}
else {
    j++;
}
```

---

However, it was not clear to me if this would produce my intended result, to execute an expression in this if-statement and to then continue with the next if-statement. So, I substitute a conditional statement and the code compiles. However, in **both** cases I get a segmentation fault, using either method with j.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

char *msg = argv[1];
char *key = argv[2];
int i, j, sl, ky, mg;
sl = strlen(key);
j = 1;
int encrypt[strlen(msg)];

if(isalpha(key) && argc == 3) {
    ;
}
else
    perror("run program from cmd line with 2 strings \n");
    return 1;

for(i = 1; i <= sl; i++) {

    (i % strlen(key) == 0) ? j = 0 : j++;

    mg = msg[i];
    ky = key[j];

    if(isalpha(msg[i])) {

        if(isupper(msg[i])) {
            msg[i] = 'A' + (('A' - msg[i]) + ('A' - key[j]) % 26);
        }

        else if(islower(msg[i])) {
            msg[i] = 'a' + (('a' - msg[i]) + ('a' - key[j]) % 26);
        }
    else {
        msg[i] = msg[i];
    }
    }
}

return 0;

}
```

Comment: From a quick glance, I think `for(i = 1; i <= sl; i++) {` should be  `for(i = 0; i < sl; i++) {`.

Comment: You're right, I changed it

Comment: `isalpha(key)` should take a single `char` (actually `int`) not a pointer. Do you have compiler warnings enabled? in the same staement, you left it too late to check `argc == 3` which is *after* you have accessed `*argv[]`

Comment: Okay, I tried isalpha((char)key) but I still get a segmentation fault

Comment: I am talking about line 14. `if(isalpha(key) && argc == 3) {`

Comment: show your (program started) command line.

Comment: You can't just make a cast and hope the problem goes away. It only hides an error. In a later line you did `if(isalpha(msg[i]))` but the line 14 has no sense.

Comment: I understand, so if I wanted to use isalpha to check the string I would to index through it in a for loop?

Comment: I thought that argv[i] was a string, therefore it is a character array, and that means char *msg = argv[1] is a char ** and in order to pass it to isalpha() I need to dereference i.e. pass as isalpha(*msg[i])

Comment: Well, If you declare it as `char *` it can't be a `char **`.

Comment: You should check `argc` before doing anything with `argv[1]` and `argv[2]`

Comment: The `return 1;` line is not part of the `else` block, so this will always return from `main` at that point.  Execution never reaches the `j` line. The only way you would get a segmentation fault is if you did not actually provide 2 commandline arugments.

Comment: Bad allocation and type: `int encrypt[strlen(msg)];` should be `char encrypt[strlen(msg)+1];` for loop should start at 1 and ending condition should be strict. Lot of other strange things, mg, ky...

Answer (score -1):

Okay well I fixed some oversights such as lines 38 and 42. This snippet of code works as a cipher but it only works some of the time.

---

```
for(i = 0; i < sl; i++) {

    (i % strlen(key) == 0) ? j = 0 : j++;

    mg = msg[i];
    ky = key[j];

    if(isalpha(msg[i])) {

        if(isupper(msg[i])) {
            encrypt[i] = 'A' + ((( msg[i] - 'A') + (key[j]) - 'A') % 26);
        }

        else if(islower(msg[i])) {
            encrypt[i] = 'a' + (((msg[i] - 'a') + (key[j]) - 'a') % 26);
        }
    else {
        encrypt[i] = msg[i];
    }
    }
}

for(i = 0; i < strlen(msg); i++) {

    printf("%c", encrypt[i]);
```

Comment: When you subtract `'A'`, for example, from `msg[i]`, you previously have checked if it is uppercase. But then you subtract `'A'` from `key[j]` too, without checking if it is uppercase (or even a letter). At the end you can print `encrypt` in a single line, no need to loop: `printf("%s\n", encrypt);`. It was declared as `char encrypt[strlen(msg)+1];`, right?